# Is it safe to autorelease objects inside an NSOperation?

Tags: cocoa, nsoperation, autorelease

I am running NSInvocationOperation-type operations in an NSOperationQueue and was wondering if it is safe to autorelease objects - That is, if it is guaranteed that the thread started for each operation has its own autorelease pool.

I didn't find any documentation autorelease pools for operations - Reading Apple's docs actually suggests I do need to define my own autorelease pool.

However:
1) I can't see any leaks in instruments, at least not more than when I allocate my own autorelease pool in the operation.

2) looking in the debugger I can see this stack trace:

```
#0  0x00fc3e82 in -[NSObject(NSObject) release] ()
#1  0x00faaa6c in CFRelease ()
#2  0x00fbf804 in __CFBasicHashDrain ()
#3  0x00faabcb in _CFRelease ()
#4  0x00fcfb8d in _CFAutoreleasePoolPop ()
#5  0x000edd0d in -[__NSOperationInternal start] ()
#6  0x000ed826 in ____startOperations_block_invoke_2 ()
#7  0x94358024 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#8  0x9434a2f2 in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()
#9  0x94349d81 in _pthread_wqthread ()
#10 0x94349bc6 in start_wqthread ()
```

So it looks as though there is a CFAutoreleasePool - Is it safe to assume this object will call release on all my autoreleased objects when the operation is complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ve written a small program to test whether `NSInvocationOperation` would create an autorelease pool for the operation:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject
@end

@implementation MyClass
- (void)performSomeTask:(id)data
{
    NSString *s = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"hey %@", data]
        autorelease];
    if ([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread])
        NSLog(@"performSomeTask on the main thread!");
    else
        NSLog(@"performSomeTask NOT on the main thread!");

    NSLog(@"-- %@", s);
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  MyClass *c = [MyClass new];

  if (argc == 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "nop") == 0)
      [c performSomeTask:@"ho"];
  else {
      NSInvocationOperation *op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
          initWithTarget:c
                selector:@selector(performSomeTask:)
                  object:@"howdy"];
      NSOperationQueue *queue  = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
      [queue addOperation:op];
      [op waitUntilFinished];

      [op release];
      [queue release];
  }

  [c release];

  return 0;
}
```

It works as follows: if "nop" is passed on the command-line, it will execute `-performSomeTask:` directly, on the main thread, with no autorelease pool in place. The resulting output is:

```
$ ./c nop
*** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x10010cca0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
performSomeTask on the main thread!
-- hey ho
```

The autoreleased string in `-performSomeTask:` causes a leak.

Running the program without passing "nop" will execute `-performSomeTask:` via an `NSInvocationOperation` on a different thread. The resulting output is:

```
$ ./c
*** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100105ec0 of class NSInvocation autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
*** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100111300 of class NSCFSet autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
*** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100111b60 of class NSCFSet autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
*** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x100105660 of class NSCFSet autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
performSomeTask NOT on the main thread!
-- hey howdy
```

As we can see, there are instances of `NSInvocation` and `NSSet` that are leaking *but the autoreleased string in `-performSomeTask:` isn’t leaking*, hence an autorelease pool was created for that invocation operation.

I think it’s safe to assume that `NSInvocationOperation` (and probally all `NSOperation` subclasses in Apple’s frameworks) create their own autorelease pools, just like the Concurrency Programming Guide suggests for custom `NSOperation` subclasses.

Comment: Did you test this on iOS 3.x? This might be a GCD implementation detail as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141123/do-you-need-to-create-an-nsautoreleasepool-within-a-block-in-gcd

Comment: @Danra AFAICT, NSOperationQueue doesn’t use GCD. Also, if you change the code above to run synchronously via `[op start]`, there’ll be no message showing that the string is leaking, which means that `NSInvocationOperation` creates an autorelease pool for the operation.

Comment: @Danra I’ve only tested this behaviour on Mac OS 10.6.6.

Comment: I’ve filed a radar asking for the documentation to explicitly state that the Foundation `NSOperation` subclasses create their own autorelease pools.

Comment: I'm assuming GCD is used because of the call to _dispatch_call_block_and_release I saw in the stack trace. Thanks for your radar, please update this thread if you get an official answer.

Comment: @Danra Yes, good point, but I’d assume that’s because of `NSOperationQueue` and not `NSInvocationOperation` per se. As for official answers, don’t hold your breath — it could take months. ;-)

Comment: Quinn the Eskimo answered my question in the Apple Developer Forums and confirmed that autorelease pools were also allocated for operations before GCD was introduced  - See https://devforums.apple.com/message/365667

Comment: @Danra Good to know. Let’s hope this makes into the documentation, too.