# Make CVDisplayLink + Automatic Reference Counting play well together

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, automatic-ref-counting

I recently switched from using NSTimer to CVDisplayLink to redraw my OpenGL animation, but i've got a little problem making it work with ARC switched on:

```
/*
 * This is the renderer output callback function.
 */
static CVReturn displayLinkCallback(CVDisplayLinkRef displayLink, const CVTimeStamp* now, const CVTimeStamp* outputTime, CVOptionFlags flagsIn, CVOptionFlags* flagsOut, void* displayLinkContext)
{
  // now is the time to render the scene
  [((__bridge BDOpenGLView*)displayLinkContext) setNeedsDisplay:YES];
  // always succeeds, because we don't actually do anything here anyway
  return kCVReturnSuccess;
}
```

The display link callback function has to be written in C, to be used as a parameter for

```
// set the renderer output callback function
CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(displayLink, &displayLinkCallback, (__bridge void*)self);
```

So i can't use `self` within in the callback, but using `((__bridge BDOpenGLView*) displayLinkContext)` produces a memory leak:

```
objc[29390]: Object 0x1001b01f0 of class NSConcreteMapTable autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
```

I read, that i have to set up an `NSAutoreleasePool` myself, but i can't with ARC switched on.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surround the code with the new `@autoreleasepool` block:

```
@autoreleasepool {
  // your c callback code here
}
```

Comment: I hit this same exact thing when I was migrating some GC code over to ARC a month ago. I got so used to blocks and the fact that [they don't need explicit autorelease pools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141123/do-you-need-to-create-an-nsautoreleasepool-within-a-block-in-gcd) that I forgot about creating one for the background thread that CVDisplayLink uses with its callbacks.