# ARC problems when creating new NSView

Tags: cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to programmatically create a window with my own custom OpenGL NSView as it's view, but I'm having a problem with ARC destroying my view. This is the code I'm using now:

```
[_window setContentView:[[MyOpenGLView alloc] init]];
```

`MyOpenGLView` is just an `NSView` where I handle all my OpenGL calls. I set up OpenGL in my `initWithFrame:(NSRect)` and then return myself. I can step through that code and it works correctly. The problem is that as soon as the `setContentView` gets called, my newly allocated `MyOpenGLView` gets autoreleased. Is there a way to make the window retain the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with my view, but with my `CVDisplayLinkOutputCallback` not having an `@autoreleasepool` block set up. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835956/make-cvdisplaylink-automatic-reference-counting-play-well-together) question gives the right way to set up a `CVDisplayLink` callback.