# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in nested dispatch_async with an NSAutoreleasePool

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, grand-central-dispatch, nsautoreleasepool

I have some code which is similar to the following code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue          = dispatch_queue_create("", 0);
dispatch_queue_t inner_queue    = dispatch_queue_create("", 0);
dispatch_async(queue,
^{
    NSAutoreleasePool* autoreleasePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSArray* objects = [self.otherObject getObjectsFromSlowQuery];

    [objects enumerateObjectsWithUsingBlock:^(id anObject, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
    {
        [anObject prepare];
        dispatch_async(inner_queue,
        ^{
            InnerObject* innerObject = anObject.innerObject;
            [self.helper doSomethingExpensiveWithObject:innerObject];
        });
        dispatch_sync(self.syncQueue,
        ^{
             [self insertIntoCollection:anObject];
        });
    }];
    dispatch_release(inner_queue);
    [autoreleasePool drain];
});
dispatch_release(queue);
```

Where `[anObject.innerObject]` is a `nonatomic` property.

I got a crash report from a user which shows an **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** in `objc_msgSend()` when trying to access a property of `innerObject` within the `doSomethingExpensiveWithObject:` call.

At first I was thinking that perhaps the `autoreleasePool` was drained so the `innerObject` instance was released before returning from `doSomethingExpensiveWithObject:` but as far as I know `anObject` should be retained by the inner `dispatch_async` call which should also keep the `innerObject` alive.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does the code work without the queues? Also, you [don't need to allocate an NSAutoreleasePool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141123/do-you-need-to-create-an-nsautoreleasepool-within-a-block-in-gcd) here.

Comment: Blocks don't effect the retain count of the objects they capture.

Comment: @DarkDust This code is called form the main thread. The code hits the file system and performs web requests so I'm doing it in the background and gradually updating the UI. I added the `NSAutoreleasePool` because many object are allocated within the expensive operations.

Comment: @user1139069: [They do.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH6-SW4) Which is why the `__block` is needed to turn that off (and make the block be able to modify the variable).

Comment: `__block` only changes whether the variable is constant or not. It has nothing to do with it's retain count.

Comment: @user1139069 `dispatch_async` calls `Block_copy` which retains the variables within the block scope.

Comment: Given that `[self.otherObject getObjectsFromSlowQuery]` is the reason why the `NSAutoreleasePool` is there in the first place, I will move the `NSAutoreleasePool` inside `[self.otherObject getObjectsFromSlowQuery]` so it doesn't affect the rest of the code.

Comment: What are the all the properties on innerObject? If you were setting innerObject with an auto released object in -prepare, that object will get eaten by the autorelease pool even if anObject is retained.

Comment: There's no particular evidence that the autorelease pool has anything to do with the crash.  But using `dispatch_async` means that the block may run on some other thread with its own autorelease pool (which might not be drained after each block is run).  So you should create/drain a pool inside the `inner_queue` block if you think `doSomethingExpensiveWithObject:` needs it.

Comment: @user1139069: No, `__block` doesn't change whether a variable is constant or not, `const` does that. [`__block` specifies whether a variable is mutable inside a block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html). And it *does* influence the retain count: If you don't use `__block` the variable gets retained. If you do use `__block` it will not get retained. This is why the `__block id unretainedSelf = self;` trick is often used.

Answer (score 1):

Instruments will make quick work of this - run with zombies and review the reference counts when it stops.

Comment: I can't reproduce the bug so running instruments with zombies doesn't help right now.